# How to keep a variable for a callback

Tags: jquery

If I have the following:

```
jqxhr = $.ajax(settings)
   .done(function(result) {
```

But I have a variable called myID that I need to reference after the ajax call is done.  Since ajax is asynchronous, I'm afraid myID will be dirty by the time .done is called.

Q: How do I save a copy of myID so that it's the correct value in the done method?  Do I use .context()?

Comment: Couldn't you either just send it so you can get it from "result", or make it another name/object inside the object (myID.id)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a closure:

```
var myID = 1;
(function(myID){ // you can choose a different variable name here to avoid confusion
    jqxhr = $.ajax(settings)
        .done(function(result) {
            alert(myID); // will still be 1
        });
})(myID)

myID = 2;
```

here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pcfeN/

Answer (score 0):

you can save into $.data and later if someone tries to re-insert - you Deny it.

This way you can save the original value